# Black Matlab image after saving using saveas function

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, save-as

I am using Matlab2007b and I would like to plot and save a 3d surface.

I manage to display the figure using `meshz(X,Y,Z)`, but when calling:

```
saveas(gca, fullfile(path,name), 'png')
```

or

`saveas(gcf, fullfile(path,name), 'png')`

or even using

> File --> Save As...

in the Figure window, the resulting figure appears black when I open it.

Also, I get the following warning in the console:

```
Warning: Problems in UIW_SetUpGLPrinting
In graphics\private\render at 142
In print at 267
In saveas at 159
```

Has anyone already experienced this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to a MATLAB version that old, but is there some equivalent to the [`Renderer` property](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-Renderer) of the figure there? I seem to remember changing to a different renderer than the default helped in some cases.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Mac?

Comment: @mikkola Thanks, I have tried changing it and I can now visualize the figure. However, still a lot of black in it... I have used set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'painters');

Comment: @SardarUsama I am under Window 7

Comment: use `zbuffer` renderer

Comment: @SardarUsama I get the same output when using `set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'zbuffer')` (i.e. still a little bit of black and many interpolation lines). Isnt there some kind of default values?

Comment: change back to `opengl` and then enter `opengl software` in the command window. If that doesn't work, try again after entering `opengl hardware` in the command window

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*some kind of default values*"

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry, indeed the term "optimal values" would have been more appropriate...